# Run service after close application in recent app (android)

Tags: android, service, background

I have a service, when application is running have not problem but when close application from recent app service close too but when I test in emulator I have not this problem, (service running after I close app in recently app), I test application in Lenovo tablet with android 4.4.2 have this problem .search in google and this site all answers Told should set START_STICKY or NO_STICKY and ... but not work in the actual device, please help

```
public class pservices extends Service {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service created.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY;

}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

}

Comment: Can you put your code how you are calling the service ..

Comment: can you show us your service declaration in manifest?

Answer (score 1):

U can try to declare ur service in manifest.xml by using android:process.
2 type of this attrs: ".xxx" and ":xxx". 
eg.

```
<service           
android:name="com.xxx.xxxservice" 
         android:enabled="true"     
         android:process=":remote">
         <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xxx.xxxservice" />
         </intent-filter>
</service>
```

It will create an independent process for ur service.